# Is there a public list of Tor public nodes that are gateway or exit nodes?

Tags: exit-relays

Where is there an official list of tor gateway and exit nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find relays on the [Relay Search](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search) page of the metrics website. If you want a list, you can also download the [network consensus document](https://metrics.torproject.org/collector.html#type-network-status-consensus-3) to get the most up-to-date list of relays. If you want only the IP addresses of exit relays, you can also download [this list](https://check.torproject.org/torbulkexitlist).

Comment: what stops governments just banning all these ips?

Comment: Some governments do ban them. When relays are blocked, people should use bridges instead which are not publicly searchable like relays are.

Comment: Why can't they also juts ban Tor Bridges?

Comment: Bridges aren't public, so the censor can't easily find all of them. See this answer here for details: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/21328/24966

Comment: warning, the https://check.torproject.org/torbulkexitlist is not comprehensive, it does not list any ipv6 addresses, of which there are several.